# How to put existing simulation tooling on the web?

Tags: java, web, simulation

I have once developed a tiny simulation tool that, given certain parameters, simulates a number of days of business so that one can gain insight into the performance of the business. I have done this in Java.

Now I would like to launch the same tool on the web, preferably with as little work as possible - as I already have working code for the matter. However, I am searching for the right approach to do so. The idea is that instead of inserting the parameters in a GUI, the user now needs to feed them to the tool through a form (or something like that). The tool then runs on the backend, and gives the results back to the user on the web page.

The thing is that it should be fast - I don't want to have users wait a minute before they get their results. My current tool simulates 100,000 days in about 3 seconds.

Basically, the question is: is it possible to run the existing Java code on the backend? If so, what would be the way to do it? If not, what would then be a good way to face this problem? (Learning other programming languages is not an issue, so if necessary that will be covered.)

Thanks in advance for thinking along with me!

Comment: The question is way too open, and will probably be closed. Yes, you can convert any existing program into a web application. There will be many ways to do it. All major languages include webapp support; in the case of Java, look at Servlets&JSPs. Any cursory search will reveal this information - and, since you did not do your homework, your question will probably be down-voted.

Comment: Convert is a dangerous word as people start to assume you can throw a converter tool at it. Redesign is the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using standard JavaEE features. I would suggest to get an application server like [Payara](http://www.payara.fish/) or [WildFly](http://wildfly.org/). 
Depending on your existing code you can port it 1:1 or you have to make some changes (e.g. if you use threads). 
If the web UI is mainly form based, I would recommend to use JSF as front-end, since it is very productive.